# Why is this particular "was" in past tense?

Tags: grammar, tenses

> He added that he saw himself then also as quite attuned to things and seemed more in touch with his surroundings than now, in an esoteric way, as one might be who **was** trying a variety of "mind expanding" offerings, a little meditation, a little "pot," a little peyote, some Eastern philosophy, etc. [Source](http://www.vintagediarist.com/steps/steps09-00.html)

Why is the bolded word in the past?

Comment: Because it’s the informal way of saying *were* in that instance.

Comment: If one were singular, surely it would have made a difference.

Comment: Because of the tense the writer chose with "he saw himself then"; that makes the seeing in the past.

Comment: No, not really. I was just teasing.  You **could** use the *were* form there in the hypothetical, but it sounds rather old-fashioned to say the least. Everything is in the past, so just stick with that.

Comment: @username901345 No, it's not subjunctive. Translate it into the present: *He sees himself now as quite attuned to things ... as one might be who is trying a variety of ...* It's simple past, simply because 'He' is talking about how he saw himself in the past.

Answer (score 2):

He **added** that he **saw** himself then also as quite attuned to things and **seemed** more in touch with his surroundings than now, in an esoteric way, as one might be who **was** trying a variety of...

The author is speaking of himself in the past tense. He continues this during the narrative. This is consistent with the rest of the passage.

The addition of the word now doesn't change anything. The "now" in the passage is still in the past.

> Just yesterday she said how much she loved life now that she was a mother. Today she's gone.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this answer is being downvoted. I think it is an acceptable answer.

Comment: @MrHen - Thank you. Sometimes people downvote because they don't want "bad questions" to be answered at all. I don't bother myself too much with downvotes. They happen for as many reasons as there are opinions here. But thanks for your concern.